# Transition maps

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $S^1=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2+y^2=1\}$, $U=\{(\cos(a), \sin(a)): a\in]0,2\pi[\}, $ $V=\{(\cos(a), \sin(a)): a\in]-\pi,\pi[\}$.

$\phi: U\to \mathbb R$ and $\psi :V \to \mathbb R$ are defined by
$$\phi((\cos(a), \sin(a))=a $$ and $$\psi((\cos(a), \sin(a))=a. $$

I want to show that $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}$ is a transition maps.
I did find that $$\psi(U\cap V) =(]-\pi, 0[\, \cup\,]0,\pi[)\not \subset]0,2\pi[=\psi(U) $$  Also I couldn't find $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to visualize how the transition maps are operating:
We know that $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}:(0, \pi)\cup(\pi, 2\pi) \rightarrow (-\pi, 0)\cup(0, \pi).$

But we know that cos and sin take the same values on $(\pi, 2\pi)$ and $(-\pi, 0)$, and it seems clear that the angle is not changed in the interval $(0, \pi)$.

Let's figure out explicitly $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}$ acts on $(0, \pi)$:

Let $\alpha \in (0, \pi) \ \Rightarrow \ \phi^{-1}: \alpha \mapsto (\text{cos }  \alpha, \text{sin }\alpha).$

Then $\psi: (\text{cos }  \alpha, \text{sin }\alpha) \mapsto \alpha$.

Thus the transition map acts as identity on $(0, \pi).$

Now let $\alpha \in (\pi, 2\pi) \ \Rightarrow \ \phi^{-1}: \alpha \mapsto (\text{cos }  \alpha, \text{sin }\alpha).$

Note that $\alpha \notin (-\pi, \pi)$, but $\alpha - 2\pi$ is! Then $\psi: (\text{cos }  \alpha, \text{sin }\alpha) \mapsto \alpha-2\pi$. To conclude we have:

$\psi \circ \phi^{-1}(\alpha)=\begin{cases}
\alpha & \text{if } \alpha \in (0, \pi) \\
\alpha - 2\pi & \text{if } \alpha \in (\pi, 2\pi)
 \end{cases} $

Note that since $\pi$ is not an element of the domain, this map is continous and smooth.

Comment: I really appreciate your help ! Thanks a lot !